# vba function to open an excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have below VBA function to open an excel file:

```
Function copie_sd()

nom_fichier = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\SD\copie_sd.xls")
If nom_fichier = False Then
    Range("A1").Select
    copie_sd = "ERREUR"
    Exit Function
End If

copie_sd = nom_fichier

End Function
```

But I get error: Run-time error '438' object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to `Dim` you variable like this.

```
Dim nom_fichier as workbook
```

Then use `set` to set it

```
set nom_fichier = workbooks.open
```

Also the following line is not going to work with an object variable

```
if nom_fichier = false then
```

This might help 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188204(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your code, you will see that `Workbooks.Open()` will not return a boolean variable, but a reference to an `Excel.Workbook` object.

your if-statement should be changed to test for `Nothing` and not for `False`:

```
if nom_fichier Is Nothing Then
    copie_sd = "ERREUR"
    Exit Function
End If
```

**Another thing:**
Do you want 'ERREUR' to be printed into the Cell **A1**?
If yes, you should call

```
Range("A1").Value = "ERREUR"
```

Comment: A UDF function cannot write to a cell. It must not have any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
Function copie_sd(ByVal fn as String) as Boolean
  copie_sd = False
  Dim sd as Workbook      
  Set sd = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn)
  If Not sd Is Nothing
       copie_sd = True
  End If    
End Function
```

And use it as

```
If copie_sd("C:\SD\copie_sd.xls") then
   ' Other things to happen after open
End If
```